# Run container in azure container registry with args

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to publish a docker image to the Azure container registry and connect to Azure App Service to be able to access the image from a link. This works fine when working with containers that do not require args to run.

However, the image I am working with only runs when I add args to the **docker run** command.

For example, docker run -p 8080:8080 ImageName:latest **start-dev**

this image requires the argument "start-dev" or "start" to be able to run.

Images published on Azure Container Registry and connected to Azure App Service work just fine unless the image requires arguments.

How can I do that on the Azure container registry?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configuring azure web app service there is a field call `Startup Command` in docker tab. For that you can add `start-dev` to append the argument to `docker run image`.